# PHP cURL get file with only a partial filename

Tags: php, http, curl, ftp

I'm pretty new to the cURL library so I hope the solution to this isn't too trivial.

Basically I have a remote directory, lets say `http://www.something.com/dir`. In this directory following files are present:

- file1.xml
- file2.xml
- file3_active.xml

Is there a way I can get the files where the filename matches the phrase 'active' into a string? Would the solution work both for http and ftp?

**EDIT**: How can I get the list/array of filenames in a remote dir? If I could do that, I could simply use `strpos`, get the full filename and use cURL the simple way.

Many Regards, 
Andreas

Comment: there are many ways to scan recursively a dir and all subdirs; strpos will match all your phrases; cUrl works for http requests, as for ftp, never tryed :)

Comment: Do you have any control over scripts run in the remote directory?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control of the remote server..

Comment: How are you getting this list of file names in your example? I.e., is there some existing mechanism by which you can list the contents of the directory?

Comment: Oh how much fun we could have if we could list files in directories we don't have control of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the list/array of filenames in a remote dir.

Off the top of my head:

1. Via an FTP dir command, if you have FTP access.
2. Via a custom PHP (or whatever) script on the remote server which generates a machine-parsable list for you.
3. Via a shellexec/popen/ssh_exec to a shell command like ls or find, run through SSH.
4. By parsing HTML from a web-server generated directory listing (i.e., as generated by Apache mod_autoindex) on the remote server.

Each of these options is going to require some action on the part of the person hosting the remote server -- so if it's completely out of your control, I think you're SOL.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it! I probably going to have to force the remote server a .htaccess with Options +Indexes in dir ;) thank you for your time!